# JPA Connection Limits

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I am building a socket server for multiple clients. Every client has his/her own thread in which there is an associated EntityManager. As long as there are many operation for each client, I close the EntityManager only when the client disconnects from the server. How many connections can my java program hold in such manner? I am using `JPA (Eclipselink) + MySQL` without `JTA`. `EntityManagerFactory` is one for all clients. How can I calculate the number of connections for my machine? Or is there a special limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your limit will be based on your database server as well as available resources on the machine where your socket server is running.  There is no limit in JPA per se.